# java poi reading and writing data in excel

Tags: java, sql, plsql

My query is..

```
Get max Erlang Traffic (Col K) for each date where Region is North
```

by using java poi

this is the code which is reading three columns (0, 2 and 10)

i want help so that i can find the maximum value from col k whoes region is north.

```
import java.io.File;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.po



public class Excel1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int columnIndex =10;
    int columnIndex1=0;
    int columnIndex2=2;

    ArrayList<String> columndata= null;
    String excelFilePath =  "C:/Users/esutmil/Desktop/Input6.xlsx";                             FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new                      File(excelFilePath));


        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        //Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Sheet worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);


        Iterator<Row> iterator = worksheet.iterator();

         columndata = new ArrayList<>();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = iterator.next();

            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();


                if(row.getRowNum() > 0){ //To filter column headings
                    if(cell.getColumnIndex() == columnIndex ||   cell.getColumnIndex() == columnIndex1 || cell.getColumnIndex() == columnIndex2){// To match column index
                        switch (cell.getCellTy`enter code here`pe()) {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            if(DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell))

                            {
                        System.out.println(cell.getDateCellValue());
                            }

                            else 
                            {
                                System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                            }


                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            columndata.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                            break;


                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        inputStream.close();




         System.out.println(columndata);
        }


}
```

This is the data in Excel sheet:

[image]

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: i want max value from column K  fro each date where region is North?

Comment: i want maximum value of column k fro each date where region is north using poi ?

Comment: show us your codes please